# ReactNative: changing state inside setInterval/useEffect not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a tinder-like clone where I want to show each 5 seconds a different user photo, I first get array of only images from matches and then with setInterval which I finally got to work inside effect I loop through images array and change active index of image, however when I console log active image, it's always the same image...

This always returns same active Index and same active image

```
console.log(images[activeImageIndex]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    getImagesArray(mapStore.blurredMatches);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(images.length>0)
        {
          flipAndNextImage();
        }
      
    }, 5000);
  
    return () => clearInterval(interval); 
  }, []);


  const getImagesArray = (users) =>
  {
      let copy = [];
      for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
      {
          copy.push(users[i].images[0]);
      }
      
      setImages(copy);
      console.log('Setting images array',images);

  };

  const flipAndNextImage= () => 
  {
    console.log(images,'images');  
    if(activeImageIndex == images.length-1)
      {
          setActiveImageIndex(0);
          console.log(images[activeImageIndex]);
      }
      else
      {
          setActiveImageIndex(activeImageIndex+1);
          console.log(images[activeImageIndex]);
      }
  };
```

Comment: because your useEffect will run only for once, and you're clearing the interval as well so that's why... remove `clearInterval` from useEffect and then it should work

Comment: @ZainKhan that's the correct implementation of useEffect

Comment: The issue might be that you're logging the index just after updating the state, which isn't updated by that time. Move the console log above set image index function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you update your activeImageIndex before logging the state